# Sum of complex exponential

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, fourier-series

Is the following sequence of partial sums bounded?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}{e^{i\,n!\,x}}$$

where $x$ is in $\left(0,2\pi\right)$ and $x$ is not a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: Isn't it bounded if it terminates at $N$? I am not sure about the terminology here, so don't take my word for it.

Comment: Sorry, I added a condition to eliminate the uninteresting cases. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what happens if $x$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$?

EDIT: The set of $x$ such that the sequence is unbounded is a dense $G_\delta$, so it also contains uncountably many $x$ such that $x/\pi$ is irrational.

Comment: I added a condition to get rid of this case. I'm more interested in the behavior other than at these points